# rails ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I am try to delete image inside a each loop like this,

```
Image.find(params[:selected_images]).each do |image|
  if image.can_be_removed_by?(current_user)
    image.destroy
  end
end
```

I got error like this:

```
ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError in ctrl#actn

Attempted to delete a stale object: Image
```

Please suggest me how to handle this situation.

Thanks

Comment: Read http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/StaleObjectError.html, It has the answer for you, then check the same in your code.

Comment: thanks, found solution from the link. To fix this added `ActiveRecord::Base.lock_optimistically = false` in environment file. If you know how to implement it using `lock_version` please post your answer

Comment: I can help you by links only, not by code in Rails... As I am baby to Rails.. Just 5 days... :-) Rather you post your solution as answer.. Which will help others,

Comment: @downvoter, can you tell me why this was downvoted? so that i can correct it